# Android: R cannot be resolved after adding a new class

Tags: android

I get the following error in eclipse: `r cannot be resolved`. However that appeared just after I added my own library as a resource to my project. It seems that eclipse cannot resolve which R to use, the library one or the project one. Note also that the library is marked with the *is library* check box in the project set-up. Also whenever I remove my library from the reference list eclipse does not show any errors, but upon compiling logCat shows a `Class Not Found` exception. How do I fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Just clean your project, and it will start work, if not work, then restart your eclipse once.

Comment: Already did that, still nothing.

Comment: Please read my updated Comment.

Comment: Yeah, restarted eclipse too, nothing though

Comment: check in drawable folder is there any file name having capital letters, in this case don't show error in drawable and we may face this problem.

Comment: check your layouts for errors and also check in imports in case you have imported com.android.R, one more thing remove your lib apply and then add it back and apply sometimes this helps me .

Answer (score 0):

R is an autogenerated class.  If you clean the project, the error should dissapear.

Answer (score -1):

R.java is not getting generated for your project which is done automatically, pls check whether something wrong with any XML file or check console if there is any **problem in XML** it will show you something related to XML or check something wrong with **importing packages**. If its not about any XML errors then check on importing that library project in your project. you may get some imports related to something like this: **com.android.R** then remove this if you see this and then manage imports again.